# Is it OK to respond with a 400 Bad Request when the client does not use AJAX?

Tags: ajax, rest, http, seo

I'm developing a web app that extensively uses modal dialogs.

The dialogs are loaded via AJAX, and the HTTP response contains just a portion of HTML, not a full HTML document. I don't want a search engine to index these publicly accessible URLs if it finds them.

I can't use a meta robots, as the HTML portion returned does not have a `<head>`.
I prefer to avoid adding every single URL to my `robots.txt`, or grouping all my URLs under a common prefix, such as `/ajax/`.

So I thought I could simply return a 400 Bad Request if the request is not performed with AJAX, i.e. does not contain the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header.

**Is `400 Bad Request` suitable for this purpose?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verbatim copy of [RFC 7231, section 6.5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1):

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot *or will not* process the request due to something that is *perceived to be a client error*

So yes, it is okay.

Comment: I'm not sure what to understand by client *error*, though. It's quite vague, isn't it?

Comment: @Benjamin 400 is deliberately vague. The rationale behind the *error* is that the client has *erred* in performing the request the way it did. This can be "fixed" by performing the same request again via AJAX.